# how could I add user permission parameter into docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to adapt this command into docker-compose.yml

`docker run -d -v /Users/eric/workspace/apache-spark-playground/es_datastore:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data --user 1000:50 elasticsearch:2.1.1`

How should I modify the following yaml sample

```
elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch:2.1.1
  hostname: elasticsearch
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"
  volumes:
    - ./es_datastore:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docker-compose docs this should work:

```
user: 1000:50
```

[source](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#cpu-shares-cpuset-domainname-entrypoint-hostname-ipc-mac-address-mem-limit-memswap-limit-privileged-read-only-restart-stdin-open-tty-user-working-dir)

Comment: don't forget the double quotes:
    ``user: "1000:50"``